# Sum of infinite series and ratio of powers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If $A = 1 + r^{a} + r^{2a} + \cdots ~~~~~ ;~~~ B= 1 + r^{b} + r^{2b} + \cdots $

Then $a/b$ is ?

I took the sum of both series :

$$A = \dfrac{1}{1-r^a}~~;~~~ B=\dfrac{1}{1-r^b}$$

But now how do we break this to find $a/b$

Answer was given to be $\log_{\frac{B-1}{B}}(\frac{A-1}{A})$. How did they get this?

Comment: Please don't end elipses with $\infty$. I seriously doubt it's what you meant. The ellipses already mean "continue whatever pattern in the reasonable way."

Comment: modulus of r is less than one so ... infinity

Comment: The convention is that ellipses without anything at the end mean "do it infinitely". If you put something at the end, as in $1+2+...+n$, then it means do it only finitely many times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

If $$A = \dfrac{1}{1-r^a}$$ $$r^a=\frac{A-1}A$$ Take logarithms of both sides to get $$a=\frac{\log \left(\frac{A-1}{A}\right)}{\log (r)}$$ Similarly $$b=\frac{\log \left(\frac{B-1}{B}\right)}{\log (r)}$$ Then $$\frac ab=\frac{\log \left(\frac{A-1}{A}\right)}{\log \left(\frac{B-1}{B}\right)}$$ Now change the base of the logarithms.

Comment: how did you get second step please? $r^a = $ one

Comment: Extract $r^a$ from $A = \dfrac{1}{1-r^a}$ and take the logarithm of both sides.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Your approach is best. However, given the unattractive form of the expected answer, once we reach $r^a=\frac{A-1}{A}$ and $r^b=\frac{B-1}{B}$ we can use logs to the base $U=\frac{B-1}{B}$, saving the change of base step.

Comment: @AndréNicolas. You are perfectly right ! May I confess that I only know one logarithm ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I know best the logarithm of my childhood, of the tables I carried around.

Comment: @AndréNicolas. This one, I forgot it so long time ago (even if I still use my slide ruler from time to time)! In fact, when I went to university, a professor was always making the statement that only one logarithm exists. By the way, in French, at least at my time, the official name for decimal logarithm was *vulgar logarithm*. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Can you recomend good resource to practice logartihm and infinite series.?

Comment: Being French, I really don't know what resource (such as a book) I could recommend. Khan academy is pretty good. For logarithms, to me, the most important is that you really understand the concept. When this will be done, the remaining will be simple. But, you are right : logarithms are very important since they play a major role in particular in limits (search on this site). Good luck in your studies. Cheers :-)